# LM2596S-5.0 Wiring

Tags: power-electronics

I'm trying to down regulate 12V to 5V and I'm using LM2596S-5.0 buck converter.
https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co-Ltd-LM2596S-5-0_C347421.html

The Pin layout is as follow:

1. Vin - 12V / 2A
2. Vout - should be 5V
3. GND
4. Feedback - Not connected
5. On/Off - Connected to GND

but instead of 5V, Vout always outputs 12V, and I cannot figure out why....  could anyone help me with directions on this?

Here is a schematic diagram:
[image]

Comment: We'll need to see the schematic of the buck converter you've built from that IC. We only know the IC you're using, not how you're connecting it to the rest of the buck converter.

Comment: also, wow, this is a brazen ripoff of texas instrument's LM2596, including simply stealing figures from the original's datasheet.

Comment: What do you mean with "Feedback – Not connected"? How is the IC to know the current voltage over the inductor without feedback??

Comment: Feedback must be connected as shown in the data sheet

Comment: Uploaded the schematic diagram. I think this is where I got lost, since my understanding was that this buck converter does not require feedback to be connected to output 5V. What would be the right wiring?

Comment: ah, interesting, once I connected Feedback with Vout, then I started to get constant 6.8V from the Vout... pleasant progress :) seems I still need to add 33µH before the connection, as per typical application diagram...

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks for pointing out, will switch to Texas instrument's LM2596 :)

Comment: @Delorean well, the take away here is that "reading the datasheet is important", the figure that shows how the chip needs to be set up was literally on the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a switching regulator, not an analog regulator. The inductor is necessary. The [data sheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2305060948_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co---Ltd--LM2596S-5-0_C347421.pdf) shows a typical application. The device does not contain an internal inductor, so the feedback must be connected in all versions, adjustable or other wise.

The difference between adjustable and fixed, is that the adjustable one requires an exernal voltage divider to sample the output whereas the fixed versions have the voltage divider internal to the device.

The data sheet contains all the information that you need. I suggest that you read up on switching regulators, specifically the buck regulator that you are using.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open your link and from there click to open the data sheet for the chip.

Your design is not using the chip correctly like buck regulators should be used, but more like linear regulators.

The design is missing for proper operation:

- the inductor required for switching regulators to work
- the flyback diode to handle the off time
- feedback to regulate the output
- proper output capacitance value for proper operation